# Como declarar uma 'data relatório' na tabela?

Tags: sql-server

Caros, há uma tabela em nosso sistema que consta inicio e fim da chamada (ligação) preciso que nessa tabela seja criada uma variavel que me traga sempre o dia desse relatório, exemplo, se o inicio e o fim da chamada estiver entre 2023-12-01 00:00:00 e 2023-12-01 23:59:59 preciso que seja armazenado '2023-12-01' como data relatório e assim por diante.

Tentei da seguinte forma mas nao obtive sucesso:

### `SELECT +@DATA_RELATORIO, INICIOCHAMADA, FimChamada, Contr_Idext,SERVICE_C FROM [Planejamento].[dbo].[TAB_DISCAGEM_Hist] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE SERVICE_ID IN (1182,784,781,1209,889,1199,783) AND InicioChamada >= '2023-11-01 00:00:00' GO`

Answer (score 0):

Se o objetivo é acrescentar somente coluna contendo a data de início da chamada, você pode utilizar algo como

```
cast (InicioChamada as date) as DataInicioChamada
```

A documentação dessa função t-sql encontra-se em [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).